# Comparing quadwords in xmm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, sse

using nasm to program in x86 assembly...

with MOVQ instruction I put m64 to xmm

```
MOVQ xmm1, qword [mymem64]
```

and now I want to compare it to zero so I can use Jcc

how it can be done and what instruction must use? (with quick look in manual I didn't found)

PS. I prefer Intel syntax :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use SSE if you want to jump conditionally depending on the value. To be able to set the flags necessary for Jcc you need to store the value in a general purpose register. If you are on 64-bit you can do something like:

```
    mov     r8,[m64]
    test    r8,r8
    jnz     .out
```

If you're on 32-bit you can check the two parts separately:

```
    mov     eax,dword [m64]
    mov     edx,dword [m64+4]
    or      eax,edx
    jnz     .out
```

Comment: I agree. However, to provide an answer to the question: use PCMPEQQ and PMOVMSKB. Also, sometimes you can replace the conditional jump with bitwise arithmetic using the mask created by the PCMP.

Comment: Ouch, PCMPEQQ is an SSE4.1 instruction, which my fairly recent quad-core doesn't even support :P

Comment: thanks, my PC has SSE4.1 but I better don't use it for this :P I thought about this way too, but MOVQ instruction was so attractive :D

Comment: Why did you find it attractive compared to a simple 64 bit mov to a general purpose register?

Comment: @Jens: well, you can use any smaller PCMPEQ, if you test the right bits after a PMOVMSKB. So that's SSE2 only, then.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it doesn't make sense to compare 64 bit operands in xmm registers, you can use general purpose registers for that.

If you need an AND or ANDN test against an operand you can use PTEST:

```
PTEST  XMM0, [yourmem128] ; compare
JZ     somewhere          ; jump if all bits of the logical and are zero
```

If you want to test two 64 bit operands, you need to use PCMPEQQ

```
PCMPEQQ  XMM0, [yourmem128] ; compare two 64 bit words
PEXTRQ   RAX, XMM0, 1       ; upper 64 bit
MOVQ     RBX, XMM0          ; lower 64 bit
OR       RAX, RBX
NEG      RAX
JZ       somewhere          ; jump if at least one word is zero
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I have used x86_64 for so long, sometimes I forget there are still some 32 bit machines out there

Comment: PEXTRQ + MOVQ is way more expensive than you want.  Use `movmskpd` (2-bit mask) or `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` (16-bit mask) / `test eax,eax` / `jnz at_least_one_match`.  test/jnz will macro-fuse into one uop, unlike OR or NEG.

Comment: Also, `neg` is pointless.  RAX is either `-1` or `0`, and `neg` of `-1` is still non-zero.  So ZF is already set appropriately by OR.  (And if you were thinking `NOT`, `NOT` doesn't set flags.  If you want to test for at least one zero, you'd use `test rax, rbx` in yours, to AND instead of OR.  you can't recover the AND result from the OR result.  But really you'd still use `pmovmskb`, and `cmp eax, 0xffff` / `jne not_all_matched`

Answer (score 2):

If you're only testing a quadword (64 bits), you should avoid SSE:

```
    CMP     qword [mymem64], 0
    JNZ     .out
```

This is true even if you're testing a full 128-bit XMM's worth:

```
    MOV     rax, qword [mymem128]
    OR      rax, qword [mymem128+8]
    JNZ     .out
```

If, however, you have a CPU with SSE 4.1, AND you need to test 128 bits, then use:

```
    VMOVDQU xmm0, xmmword [mymem128]
    VPTEST  xmm0, xmm0
    JNZ     .out
```

Comment: If you have an all-ones constant in a register (like `pcmpeqd xmm0,xmm0`), you can `vptest xmm0, [mem]` / `jnz` to still test all the bits in the memory operand.  (The AVX encoding doesn't require alignment for memory operands.)  https://uops.info/ shows that modern Intel CPUs can micro-fuse `ptest` with a memory operand so it's still only 2 total uops, same as `pcmpeqb`/`pmovmskb`.